# Limit of $ f(x^2) $ having only the graph of piecewise function $ f $

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions, piecewise-continuity

I have the following piecewise function $ f(x) $:

[image]

And I have to find the $\lim_{x \to -1^{-}} f(x^2) $

I have defined approximately the piecewise function $ f(x) $ based on the graph:

\begin{align} f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\approx\frac{3}{2}x + \frac{7}{2} &,   -\infty < x < -1 \\
\approx3 &,   x = -1 \\
2 &,   -1 < x < 1 \\
\approx3 &,   x = 1 \\
1& ,   1 < x < \infty \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

If I were looking for the limit for $\lim_{x \to -1^{-}} f(x) $ the answer would be $ 2 $ but I'm confused when it comes to $ f(x^2) $.

The answer provided is $ 1 $ but I can't figure out how the function is transformed when is squared so the limit approaches 1.

Comment: I can see why would it be $ y\to1 $ as $ x= 1, x^2 = (-1)^2 = 1 $ But, why is the direction reversed?

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterForeman. I get it now. I also was missing that squaring both sides reverses the inequality if both numbers are negative. I can see the change in direction from there.

Feel free to repost the same as the answer to the question I'll mark it as the best answer.

Comment: Suppose $x$ is almost $-1$ (approaching frim the left), say $x=-1.001$. What is $f(x^2)$ then? How about when $x$ is even closer, say $x=-1.000001$. What is $f(x^2)$ now? Is $f(x^2)$ tending towards a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sequential definition of the limit or otherwise one has
$$\lim_{x\to-1^-}f(x^2)=\lim_{y\to1^+}f(y)=1$$